# Is it dangerous to keep an admin page to administer your database?

Tags: php, mysql, security

Hey guys I have an admin page that checks if you are admin before submitting any queries, and contains a header to the index page if you are not admin, but I am worried about protecting the page. I am concerned someone may be able to destroy my database with it. Does anyone have any recommendation into protecting a page like this, if not, should I just manually admin my database through phpmyadmin and delete the page all together?

Example

```
function isAdmin(){
      return ($this->userlevel == ADMIN_LEVEL ||
              $this->username  == ADMIN_NAME);
   }

 if(!$session->isAdmin()){
         header("Location: ../index.php");
         return;
      }
```

The admin value is stored in the database and represents ADMIN_LEVEL

Comment: Out of curiosity, what code are/were you using to check to see if the current user was the admin?  I agree with Slokun though, you have PHPmyAdmin for a reason.  You can also get something like SequelPro http://www.sequelpro.com/ to admin your DB from the desktop if you want.  I like the apps interface and it's another option for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather common for websites to have an administrators section, but you do have to make sure, on every page, before anything is inserted, removed, etc. that the user is an admin, something you are doing.

However, having a page that lets you enter explicit SQL statements and executes them probably isn't a good idea. You could too easily enter something wrong, and it does leave a MUCH larger security hole, should something go wrong. Larger as in, easier to access system admin-level commands, depending on the setup.

Not to mention the ease of messing something up yourself.

Direct SQL queries is why you have phpMyAdmin. Admin sections are normally intended to be a GUI frontend of your data, just as the website for regular users is, but with a greater range of abilities. Such things as being able to list all users, edit a user's data through a controlled form, then updating or deleting them with a button.

Comment: thanks for your advice. The page would just be a GUI to delete topics and ban users and such.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty well protected to me. With your configuration as is, is it any more likely or easy to hack your site and not your dev pc which runs the phpMyAdmin? Probably not a whole lot more likely. Sounds like you did everything right. If you're still worries you could limit your execution of sql to select statements which are rather innocuous in terms of db danger.

Comment: thanks for your input man, appreciate it. I feel a bit better now lol.